# Java SAX: how to use DefaultHandler in the main class

Tags: java, xml, class, sax

I have made a sax parser, having the main class that has the main method, and setting the parser using `XMLReader.setContentHandler(myCustomParserClass)`, which is a separate class that extends DefaultHandler:

```
 public class SAXHandler {

    public static void Main(String args[]) {
       XMLReader.setContentHandler(myCustomParserClass); } 
  }

  class MyCustomParserClass extends DefaultHandler { ... }
```

But I have a problem. It is an assignment, and the condition is that the main class has to extend the DefaultHandler, such as:

```
    class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

      public static void main(String args[]) { ... }

      public void startElement(String uri...) { }
      public void endElement(String uri...) { }
```

And I don't really have an idea how do I implement the XMLReader, what do I set as the content handler when the class that is the parser... is also the class that has the main method and there has to be one only this one class in the file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't really like SAX, from what I've looked at there are better options for XML, but it was for an assignment, so it was compulsory to use SAX in the app, as it was automatically checked for adherence to the criteria.

Comment: you will get fired for not using it... you should quit :)

Answer (score 1):

The DefaultHandler class shouldn't contain a `main()` method at all. The way you use the DefaultHandler class is a little tricky. It contains a number of methods that are meant to be overridden, because by default... they do nothing.

The SAXParser works by sequentially reading the XML file. It detects when an XML node is opened or closed and uses a DefaultHandler subclass (in your case, SAXHandler) to determine what to do as each node is opened or closed. It's helpful to think of the DefaultHandler class as a dictionary of sorts, which the parser will use as a reference while reading through the XML.

`startElement()` is called when the parser detects an opening tag of a node, and `endElement()` is called when the parser detects a closing tag of a node. The parameters of each of these methods contains information about the node itself, which were passed back from the parser. The code you write within these methods tells the parser what to do as it encounters the corresponding opening/closing tags.

The methods that you'll likely want to override are `startElement()`, `endElement()`, and possibly also `characters()`. The parameters you're most likely to use are `localName`, `qName`, and `attributes`, which is really a list of `Attribute` objects, whose members can be accessed with `getIndex(int index)` and whose values can be accessed with `getValue()`.

Have a look at this tutorial, it's how I learned how to use SAX; the demo was what helped make it clear for me: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parser.htm

Documentation for DefaultHandler:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html

Comment: Yes, exactly, in my solution I had a separate class that implemented the DeafultHandler, and then used that class in my main class, the usage of the DeafultHandler with the main class does seem odd, if not wrong to me, too. However, I solved it that I instantiated it as such: `setContentHandler(new MainClass())`, and it worked.